# Core data fetch grouped by an attribute in another entity

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

[image: Core data definition]

I have three Core Data entities:

- StoreInventory models the Products in a GroceryStore, which includes the aisle where the Product is located in the Grocery Store.
- GroceryStore models a grocery store. It has a to-many relationship with StoreInventory.
- Product models a food product. It has a to-many relationship with StoreInventory.

I’d like to get a list of all Grocery Stores in the Central and Southern regions. I want the list grouped by the aisle where the Product “Froot Loops” is located, including a group for GroceryStores that do not carry Product “Froot Loops”.

An example might help. Here’s the data:

```
Entity: GroceryStore
storeName     storeRegion
Store 110     Central
Store 220     Southern
Store 330     Northern
Store 440     Central

Entity: Product
productName
Froot Loops
Cap’n Crunch

Entity: StoreInventory
aisle   groceryStore   product
3       Store 110      Froot Loops
4       Store 110      Cap’n Crunch
3       Store 220      Froot Loops
5       Store 330      Froot Loops
```

And here’s what I’d like for the fetch results:

```
Group "Aisle 3"
    Store 110
    Store 220

Group "(No aisle)"
    Store 440
```

I haven’t been able to write a single Core Data fetch request that will accomplish this. Any ideas? Is it even possible with a single Core Data fetch request?

Objective C is preferred over Swift, although any help at all is appreciated.

(By the way: I’d like to avoid creating StoreInventory entities for every combination of GroceryStore and Product, with an invalid aisle number to indicate when there is no relationship. However, with that I could probably write a fetch on StoreInventory to do the job.)

Comment: Fetch the GroceryStore objects you are interested in using a request then do the rest in your code.

Comment: I’d like to get Core Data to do as much of the work as possible. Fetching all the GroceryStore objects and then searching/sorting/grouping in code can be pretty expensive.

Comment: Well I don’t think Core Data can do much more than I described before, if you have other requirements you might be better of not using Core Data and work directly with an Sql database.

Comment: Off topic, your model looks a little strange. It says that there can be only one product in an aisle (StoreInventory), shouldn’t it be many products in an aisle that is a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: I’m afraid you might be right about Core Data’s limitations. Hopefully somebody will have an “a-ha” moment that’ll unlock something I hadn’t thought of. As far as the model goes, if there are m GroceryStores and n Products then there can be up to m x n StoreInventory entities recording the relationship between each product and each store.